# Json file struggling with the length

Tags: javascript, html

So, i got everything almost working as i want it, just a mistake that im struggling. Everytime i search for an item, when the result for that item shows the length is repeated.

[When i search for ox there are 2 results and that is correct, but the length (2) shows in both of them, i only display one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iKBi.png)

[Code]

```
const resultHtml = (itemsMatch) => {
  if (itemsMatch.length > 0) {
    const html = itemsMatch
      .map(
        (item) => ` 
        <span>${itemsMatch.length}</span>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="items-img">
        
        </div>
        <div class="items-info">
          <h4>${item.title}</h4>
          <small>${item.path}</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    `
      )
      .join('');

    //console.log(html);

    itemList.innerHTML = html;
  }
};
```

////

Question [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnfRi.png)

I got one more question, i was trying to get the image from the Json and what i got was the path haha

[why the apth and not the img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnfRi.png)

```
const resultHtml = (itemsMatch) => {
  if (itemsMatch.length > 0) {
    const html =
      `<span class="items-results">${itemsMatch.length} Resultados</span>` +
      itemsMatch
      .map(
        (item) => ` 
      <div class="card">
        <div class="items-img">
          ${item.image}
        </div>
        <div class="items-info">
          <h4>${item.title}</h4>
          <small>${item.path}</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    `
      )
      .join('');

    console.log(html);

    itemList.innerHTML = html;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move `<span>${itemsMatch.length}</span>` out of your `map` callback, it will not repeat for each item. [Read more about map() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Replace:

```
 const html = itemsMatch
  .map(
    (item) => ` 
    <span>${itemsMatch.length}</span>
    ... more HTML here
    `
  )
  .join('');
```

With this:

```
const html = `<span>${itemsMatch.length}</span>` + (
  itemsMatch
  .map(
    (item) => `
  <div class="card">
    <div class="items-img">
    
    </div>
    <div class="items-info">
      <h4>${item.title}</h4>
      <small>${item.path}</small>
    </div>
  </div>
`
  )
  .join('')
);
```

**Regarding your image issue:**

You are just outputting the path and that's why it's printing out just the path. If you are trying to display an image then put the path as source of `<img>` tag.

So, instead of just:

```
${item.image}
```

Use:

```
<img src="${item.image}">
```

Comment: I got one more question, i was trying to get the image from the Json and what i got was the path haha 

[...][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qu8X.png

Comment: @Barrote Edit your question and create a new section with the new code and the screenshot. I'll edit my answer to guide you.